# Saving html document to mysql in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

This might be useless question,I don't know exactly. I have a form comprising of many fields. Whenever user clicks a button, I want this html/php document to get saved in database along with the current values entered by user.

Is it possible to do so? If yes, please let me know the procedure.

For example you can take any html/php document like sign-up forms.

Comment: Please provide code then we can help you..

Comment: Instead of saving the html file, you should save the form datas into database?

Comment: Taking data from a form and putting it into a database is basically what PHP was designed to do from day one. In other words, this is a very basic operation, and we're not here to teach you the basics.

Comment: @MarcB I guess you didn't studied my post carefully.I request you to please read it once more before commenting something.I said I want to save HTML document in database,along with its values.I have a project where I need to save it.and whatever you are saying its just database connectivity thing.I don't want that answer.All the divs and each everything should get store in database,which we can see on  source code of a html document;.

Comment: @Sadikhasan Why you want code for it?just thing of any registration form,which is made of divs,tables..etc

Comment: so how's that any different? some JS to get the .innerHTML of your document or chunk of document that you want, and then sent it over as a standard form submission. You're not seeing the forest for the trees...PHP couldn't care less whether you're sending over a number or a 500 page document. it's just some text coming in via HTTP.

Comment: @MarcB Ok Ok,got it,that means I need to use inner html property for this,but this would only save the body part I guess?

Comment: no, you can save the entire DOM if you want. question is... why would you want to? 5 years down the road you try to load an old saved form and end up with the scaffolding from 3 site redesigns back. You should be saving ONLY the data from the form itself. the rest of the html should be utterly irrelevant.

Comment: well actually My form is generated by XSD document.And any change to that xsd will change my HTML document.When this form is made from XSD,user will enter all the data and save in database as a JSON string,So after sometime,user may need to edit the document whatever he has saved,then how I supposed to that,for this I would be making HTML form through JSON string which is very tough as my JSON string comprises of many deep tree.So I thought of saving the html document  in the database.Hope you did get this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery to solve what you are asking for like this:

```
$(function() {
    var document = $("html").html();
    console.log(document);
});
```

And then post the document variable to your database.